# Top alignment of beamer slide does not work

Tags: beamer

as far as I understood, the option [t] for a frame in latex beamer will cause the content of that frame to be positioned on top (and not in the center). However, in my case this is not so. A minimal example would be:

```
\begin{frame}[t]
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=6.0cm]{picture.pdf}
 \end{center}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Text 1.
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[t]
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics[height=6.0cm]{picture.pdf}
 \end{center}
 \begin{itemize}
  \item Text 2.
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

What I want is that the picture remains at the same position and Text 1 is replaced by Text 2 on the next slide. However, if the texts require different space, latex nevertheless tries to "center" both slides, i.e., when I go from slide 1 to slide 2 I see a jump in the position of the picture.

I am grateful for any help!!!

Comment: The minimal example should be compilable (with documentclass, packages, etc) and image files provided if they are needed. In any case, without the pictures (employing the `demo` option of `graphicx` package) I do not see any jump.

Comment: Do you see this jumping also in the code above? I can not reproduce this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related with two issues: having your frame positionned on top does not seem to be your main concern. I mean, you can achieve what you want without using this option.

For all issues related with having your text at the same position on both slides, you should have a look at chapter 9 from beamer manual. For example you can use the overprint environment:

```
\begin{frame}
   \begin{center}
      \includegraphics[height=6.0cm]{picture.pdf}
   \end{center}
   \begin{itemize}
     \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<1> \item Text 1
        \onslide<2> \item Text 2
     \end{overprint}
   \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Hey sztruks. Thanks for the idea with the overprint environment. Didn't know that before and this solved my problem!